# How to create a dyraph with multiple x-axis labels?

Tags: r, dygraphs

I'm working with a lot of rank data that would benefit from a way to simultaneously display its respective year on the x-axis. For example, I want to create the following graph [adapted from the dygraph gallery](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-weekends):

[image]

Note how the rank information (red arrow) for a particular weekend (green arrow) are both displayed on the x axis.

I know this might not be possible with dygraphs now, at least it wasn't available in [these demos](http://dygraphs.com/tests/), so I guess my follow up question would be are there any plans to make this possible (how about in the [r] {dygraph} package)? Apparently a plotter called [flot](http://sohu.io/questions/1144590/multiple-x-axis-tick-sets-in-flot) can do this.

**UPDATE 1**

If indeed this feature does not exist yet, then the following, although potentially obvious to Dygraph developers, is a thought for accomplishing the task *easily* (perhaps I'm wrong). At first I thought it would be necessary to provide input data of the form shown in Table A

[image]

However such input is a major deviation from the existing Dygraph parser model who expects one abscissa. Such suggests that a modification to the parser to accept a "Dual Label" option, requiring that both labels be contained in a single abscissa element as in Table B, would be easier. Thereafter, with the option specified, the parser would manage CSV as it usually would with the exception that it is now "bin cognizant" and detects division between labels 1 and 2 by use of an acceptable delimiter (in this case a single quotation mark - maybe not the best choice) and divisions between label 1 abscissa elements by name change. Behind the scenes each point gets its unique x coordinate and the "Dual Label" option causes the dygraph to visually scoot up a couple pixels to accommodate an extra label. Not sure how to handle full zoomed scrolling put simply leaving a label 1 element centered until an adjacent label 1 element comes on screen is an option.

`Dygraphs rule!`

Comment: Any reason for the R tag?

Comment: is this what you want? http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_dygraphs.html

Comment: No. I do not request a range selector (although that will be a nice addition). The goal is to be able to label the x-axis with both 'Weekend 1-n' labels as well as 'r 1-m' labels

Comment: @Gregor: There is a small corner of programming for mobile devices that uses R as name for something. I generally just remove them when they show up. In this case there is a 'dygraphs' package and the questioner may have misspelled it. So I'm not editing the tags, but I would ask that some code and data be presented.

Comment: [r] in this post is a statistical computing language being used for ranking analysis. http://www.r-project.org/. [r] users benefit from Dygraph support in the form of a package. I seek to continue using dygraphs in my [r] based analysis. Please do not remove the [r] tag.

Comment: @zelusp Yes, BondedDust and I are both primarily active with R. Would you edit your question, as BondedDust also suggests, to include some code?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do this with dygraphs now. As you say, there's a fairly deep assumption that there's only a single x-axis.

Your best bet would be to either modify the [existing legend plugin](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/57894b14ebc7a0012b23c7abb99747d75e5a74cf/src/plugins/legend.js) to do this, or to create a new plugin which renders just the "Weekend 1", "Weekend 2" line. While the plugins API isn't official yet, it is at least [somewhat documented](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/tree/57894b14ebc7a0012b23c7abb99747d75e5a74cf/src/plugins).

If you get this to work, please share your code!

Comment: I figured this much. I'll take a look and see what I can do.